# How to set the correct local time zone in git bash?

Tags: windows, git, timezone, msysgit, git-bash

I am using git-bash on a Windows system.

The Windows clock shows local time, but inside git-bash everything is in GMT time:

```
$ date
Mon Mar 31 16:08:57 GMT 2014
```

Also setting TZ will not change things:

```
$ TZ="Europe/Berlin" date
Mon Mar 31 16:09:01 GMT 2014
```

Similarly all times it `git log` are GMT only.

Is there a way to set the correct timezone in git-bash?

Comment: By "correct", do you mean "local"?

Comment: It should display "18:09:01 CEST 2014" instead of "16:09:01 GMT 2014". But it is ignoring both the time zone set in windows and the time zone set with TZ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows the `TZ` variable seems to work [differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

To get the German timezone you have to write:

```
TZ=GST-1GDT date
```

If you set it to some "invalid" value like `"Europe/Berlin"` it will default to GMT.
The same seems to happen on my system when TZ is not set at all.

With the above setting I get `Thu Apr 17 16:23:23 GDT 2014` which is not exactly the same as `Thu Apr 17 16:23:23 CEST 2014`, but at least the time looks right.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to create these timezone codes, since the linked documentation seems to have been retired by Microsoft sometime in the years since this answer was written. Is there a way to map known Unix timezone names to the Windows equivalents?

Comment: @Mindstormer619 Don't know about mapping, but you can use a [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160820071651/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885(v=vs.80).aspx) to view the link or just [change the VS version in a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885%28v=vs.160%29.aspx) to something more recent.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here in my script. Windows was showing 15:47 and the "date" command in gitbash was answering 13:47.

```
export TZ="CEST-2"
```

This fixed the problem for me. I wanted Paris time.