# How to see What was server time when I pulled changes from git?

Tags: git, github

How to see What was server time when I pulled changes from git?

I don't care about when the developer made changes and about his time zone. I care about when in server time the last 5 changes were pulled into the server, so I can compare it with other server logs.

Comment: There is only 1 time, the time fomr the server should be equal to the time of all users. What time-difference are you afraid of ?

Comment: my developer is in india, it's giving me gmt +5:30 time, while my server is gmt -7 time. what should be the right command?

Comment: This info is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23900181/724039.  (`git log --date=local`)

Comment: @Luuk This is not pull time, it's commit time.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not store the pull time anywhere for you, but it leaves traces on your file system. Among other things, `git pull` will change the files in `.git/refs/remotes/origin`.

If you look at

```
ls -la .git/refs/remotes/origin
```

each file there corresponds to a remote-tracking branch, and each file is most likely dated as of the last time it was changed through a pull, or a fetch. Or a push, too.

The most recent of the files in there is most likely dated the time when you last ran `git pull` or `git fetch`.

For example, I have an old sandbox on my computer:

```
$ ls -la .git/refs/remotes/origin/
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 32 Apr 13  2022 HEAD
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 41 Oct 22 15:02 ignore-revs
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 41 Oct 22 14:41 master
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 41 Oct 22 14:41 test-build
```

This tells me that I first cloned the repo into that sandbox on April 13, last fetched `master` and `test-build` on Oct 22 at 14:41, but now I can't say if fetched `ignore-revs` at 15:02 or if I pushed it from this sandbox.