# How can I change my git timezone offset?

Tags: git, github, timestamp, commit

I read that the --date argument when adding a commit can be used to specify the timestamp and the timezone offset. I'm curious if there's a way to globally set just the timezone offset so it matches my timezone.. I'm in EST which is -0500 from UTC, and whenever I commit and push to Github my contributions never shows up on the correct day. IE. it's 2:00 AM where I am but git sets the timezone offset to UTC. Now when I commit/push my changes to Github they will show up as 9 PM UTC.

I've got a bit of OCD acting up right now.

Comment: Just to clarify: The times are correct but you want the dates that are displayed to you in another time zone? Because if you are 02:00 -0500 then 21:00 UTC (9 PM) is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @musiKk It's the other way around - I'm in EST but git always commits in UTC, so everything I commit is instantly 5 hours behind. It's strange but Github shows an accurate time based on my browser's location but the commits are still in UTC

Comment: That sounds weird. Your operating system might be relevant. I use Linux (Ubuntu) and everything is correct. I'm pretty sure the same goes for my Windows machine at home.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the correct local time zone in git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766678/how-to-set-the-correct-local-time-zone-in-git-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Git gets the time zone from your system's configuration, so if you configure your system correctly then Git should use the correct time zone.  Run `date +%z` to check your system's configuration.

Perhaps Git is using the correct time zone but GitHub is displaying the time using the wrong time zone.  After you create a commit, run `git show` and check the offset.  If it's correct, then the problem is with GitHub.

Comment: I've just checked with `git show` and my timezone is ok, like `Date:   Mon Jan 28 14:05:32 2019 +0200` However GitHub Releases web page shows `created an hour ago` for tag that has been created and pushed right now. I'm using `git version 2.20.0.windows.1`

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same issue after moving to another counter. Just clean your cookies, this should help you. It fixed my issue.