# How to change the git output time zone in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm in gmt+8. but git output time zone  is incorrect,
windows terminal display time is correct.
how to change the git output correct time in vscode??

Comment: That doesn't look like "git output", it looks like part of the prompt for your shell.

Comment: check this, maybe your git timezone after git install wasn't set properly, this has nothing to do with vscode as its just running git commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766678/how-to-set-the-correct-local-time-zone-in-git-bash

Comment: its work in vscode output, I've tried key `date` in gitbash, that display correct time,